# Can't delete rows - UITableView iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm trying to clear a UITableView. First of all, I tried to clear with `[self.tableView reloadData]; listOfPosts = nil` but the tableView still showing 10 rows. Then I tried to delete row by row but the result was the same.

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

NSLog(@"Number of sections: %i", [self.tableView numberOfSections]); // => 1
NSLog(@"Number of rows in section 0: %i", [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]); // => 10

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSMutableArray *rowsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int nPosts = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
for (int i = 0; i < nPosts; i++) {
    [rowsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
}
currentPostList = nil;
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithArray:rowsToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];                         
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadData];

NSLog(@"Rows after endUpdates: %i", [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]); // => 0
NSLog(@"Visible rows: %i", [[self.tableView visibleCells] count]); // => 0

// But the tableView still show 10 rows

}];
```

PD: I'm using a UITableViewController so self.tableView is generated automatically

(I'm sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You shouldn't need to *both* animate your changes *and* reload the table. What happens if you remove one or the other (but not both)?

Comment: If I comment `[self.tableView reloadData]` I get the same result. The same with `[self.tableView beginUpdates] ... [self.tableView endUpdates]`

Comment: Wondering whether this might be down to block-related shenanigans with `currentPostList`. What if you put all of the code in the block into a new method (say, `-clearTable`), and call that from the block (`[self clearTable]`)?

Comment: unfortunately it does not solve the problem

Comment: Dumb question, maybe: are you sure that the table view that you're seeing on screen is actually the one being manipulated here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to change the value that goes into the method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

That is what will alter the amount of rows in your table view. Reloading the table won't do anything unless your model has changed the value that this method states.

Comment: That's my code:
`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [currentPostList count];
}`

Comment: You don't have any prototypes that are there by default do you? Have you attempted to load the table view without any data. To see if it still has those 10 cells before you even do anything?

Comment: I make that:

1. Get info from server
2. Show this info in a TableView
3. If the user tap a "clear button", I want to clear the rows
4. Get info form server

Comment: Have you checked if the 10 cells are still there before any data is put into the table?